# atomic_wait and similar methods in c++ 20 and g++ 10.2

Tags: c++, c++20, gcc10, g++10

I am compiling with g++ 10.2 using `-std=c++20` but i get errors like `error: ‘atomic_notify_one’ is not a member of ‘std’`. I see in the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_notify_one) that those methods are supported in c++20. Do i miss something?

Comment: You miss the fact that `-std=c++20` does not mean that all C++20 features are available. According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html, the relevant P1135R6 has not yet been implemented in libstdc++.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand neither g++-10.2 nor g++-10.3 does not support `atomic_notify_one`. However, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/n8a5jx4dz) the trunk version of the compiler (in which `__cplusplus` is equal to 202002), as well as my local unstable version of the compiler g++-11.0 (in which `__cplusplus` is also equal to 202002) perfectly cope with the functions `atomic_notify_one`, `atomic::notify_one`

And BTW, unfortunately I did not find official support information. In some places it is introduced in g++-10, in some it is still not implemented yet. [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) says it is implemented in g++-11, so I guess it is. In general I would not rush to use `atomic_notify_one` in production